# Populate Map<Enum, ObjectReference> on Bean creation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, collections, javabeans

I have a class:

```
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ServiceFactory {
    private CustomerService customerService;
    private ClientService clientService;

    private Map<OrderType, SettlementService> settlementServiceMap;

    public ServiceFactory(CustomerService customerService, ClientService clientService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
        this.clientService = clientService;
        this.settlementServiceMap = new EnumMap<OrderType, SettlementService>(OrderType.class){{
            put(CUSTOMER_CREDIT_ORDER, customerService);
            put(CLIENT_CREDIT_ORDER, clientService);
            put(CLIENT_DEBIT_ORDER, clientService);
        }};
    }

    public SettlementService provideService(OrderType orderType){
        Optional<SettlementService> settlementService = Optional.ofNullable(settlementServiceMap.get(orderType));
        if (!settlementService.isPresent()){
            throw new ApplicationException("Wrong order type");
        }

        return settlementService.get();
    }
}
```

I'm getting `NullPointerException` since the services have not been initialized. A map contains orderType as a key and reference to service as a value. What is the proper way of populating the map along with services?

Comment: Have you tried autowiring the services? They will need the `@Service` annotation for that.

Comment: That constructor must not be getting invoked - why is there @NoArgsConstructor? Also, those instance fields should be `final`.

Comment: I've tried @Autowired on constructor. Didn't help. I've put @NoArgsConstructor, because without that I'm getting `No default constructor found;` exceptions.